# "javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error; PATH methods failing

Tags: windows, powershell, path, redhat-enterprise-linux, eclipse

I'm taking Data Structures right now and I've been having issues with Java on and off throughout, but now it just won't work on my computer anymore.

I downloaded the Eclipse Temurin JDK 17 for Windows 10 through the JavaCodingPack and suspiciously, I would get the "javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error in Powershell when typing "javac * java", but could run in VSCode just fine. Sometimes, I would need to run the JavaCodingPack again to get programs to run (I don't know why). The past week however, no program will run in VSCode. I attempted to change my PATH variables. My user PATH was correct, but I updated my system PATH to match and that didn't work. I updated the system PATH to direct to JAVA_HOME. That didn't work.

I tried to uninstall Eclipse JDK and install the RedHat OpenJDK instead. I made sure the user and system PATH was updated to match RedHat and everything. Still, I could not run in Powershell or VSCode. I continue to get the "javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error in Powershell and no print output in VSCode.

My lab assistant also messed with the settings.json file in VSCode which I don't think is helping much. VSCode keeps telling me the version of Java I have isn't accessible since the lab instructor messed with things (and I messed with them again after the RedHat install). This is probably superfluous, but I thought I'd mention it.

My computer isn't letting me screenshot my System Properties, but please ask any questions for further information that might be helpful!

Comment: What do you get when you enter $env:path and is this correct.

Comment: C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-17-openjdk-17.0.9.0.9-1\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-17-openjdk-17.0.9.0.9-1\bin;C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;

This is accurate, I'm assuming the doubling of my JDK is from PATH and JAVA_HOME?